# Did the Doctor take a UK driving test before using Bessie?

Tags: doctor-who

It is well known that the third Doctor drove a canary-yellow Edwardian roadster, Bessie, that was used as his primary mode of transportation in several stories.

Is it known whether the Doctor actually took a driving test, or did the Brigadier allow him to break the law?

Comment: The Doctor is hundreds of not thousands of years old and hence eligible for exemption as he would likely be driving before 1935, when licencing became compulsory.

Comment: @Valorum He may have experienced hundreds if not thousands of years of chronological time, but the tricky thing with time travel is where does the driving fit in on his time line.  EG He could have driven post-1935 before he drove Pre-1935.

Comment: @Valorum He might have had a hard time proving that to the DVLA though. Did the 3rd Doctor have psychic paper...?

Comment: He would have a problem these days as UK driving licences have the bearer's photo, and it might have the wrong face on.

Comment: Consider the number of people convicted each year of driving without a licence.  The Doctor isn't known for his rigourous adherence to rules.

Comment: *Spearhead from Space* ends with the brigadier saying that the first order of business (specifically before the Doctor can pick out a car) is to get the Doctor's paperwork for U.N.I.T. employment in order and asks what the Doctor's name is.  The Doctor supplies the obviously false name "John Smith," and though we never see or hear the brigadier's response, he a apparently accepts it.

Comment: @GordonD - Someone who was driving before 1935 doesn't need a licence at all. No photo? No problem...

Comment: There are also provisions in UK law for giving diplomatic immunity to people employed as experts for a UN agency, or on missions for them, although I do not think these have been invoked in the series.

Comment: @GordonD AIUI UK licenses issued since 1998 are photocards with a 10 year expiry, but paper licenses remain valid until the holder either moves house or turns 70. So there are still a bunch of valid paper licenses in circulation.

Comment: @PeterGreen Ah, not having a licence myself I wasn't aware of that. Thanks for the information.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You'll be pleased to [learn](https://classicdoctorwhocomics.wordpress.com/second-doctor-comics/#:%7E:text=The%20Faithful%20Rocket%20Pack) that the good Doctor holds a *'Universe Driving Licence'*, entitling him to fly (and presumably drive) anything anywhere.

[image]
<sub><sup>[**The Faithful Rocket Pack (comic story)**](https://tardis.fandom.com/wiki/The_Faithful_Rocket_Pack_(comic_story))</sup></sub>

Comment: "Universe Driving License" - presumably valid throughout the universe.

Comment: Sounds like Psychic Paper to me.

Comment: @Xavon_Wrentaile *Looks* like Psychic Paper to me.